# Issues when trying to test Windows Phone 8 app with actual device

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, wcf-data-services

I actually have a problem while trying to test my application directly on my Windows Phone 8 device.

I have a SQL Database, and my Windows Phone 8 application connects to it successfully through a WCF Dataservice when using the emulator.

When I try to run the application with the Phone plugged to the computer, it doesn't run anymore, and I get those kind of unhandled exception before the managed limit:

```
`System.Net.WebException`
`System.Data.Services.Http.WebException`
`System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceTransportException`
`System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException`
`System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException`
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like a connectivity issue. Let me guess: the WCF service is hosted on your computer, and you're calling it at the `127.0.0.1` address

Comment: Right, it is hosted on my computer.
I tried with 127.0.0.1 and 169.254.80.80 (which is the IP address of the emulator), but when I try with my real IP Address, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Did you verify settings of your Firewall?

Comment: I did, currently it is disabled.

Comment: 169.254.80.80 doesn't seem to be the `local` address of the machine on your network. Make sure you open the firewall settings and open the correct incoming ports. Make sure that your service proxy points to **that** address instead of 127.0.0.1